# jQuery Plugin not working for elements added dynamically

Tags: jquery

How do I get a jQuery Plugin working for elements added dynamically? I'm trying to add  few date pickers to the DIV  **datesList** each time you cick the Add button. The plugin doesnt work for the textboxes that are added dynamically. Can some one please advice?

Thank You

**HTML**

```
<div class="datesList">
    <div class="date">
        <input type="text" class="date-picker"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="addDate">
    Add Date
</div>
```

JS

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker();

$(".addDate").click(function(){
   var dList = $(".datesList");
   dList.find(".date").first().clone(false).appendTo(dList);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jquery on() http://api.jquery.com/on/ like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.addDate', function() {
     YOUR FUNCTION
});
```

For better perfomance instead of $(document), use  the closest DOM element that is loaded for the first time

Comment: sorry mate it doesnt work,would you please be able to do me a jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $(".date-picker").datepicker();

 $(".addDate").click(function(){
   var dList = $(".datesList");
   dList.find(".date").first().clone(false).appendTo(dList);
   $(".date-picker").datepicker();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this works but you may not like the way i did it

```
$(".date-picker").datepicker();

$(document).on('click', '.addDate', function() {
    var dList = $(".datesList");
    var newinput = $('<input type="text" />').attr('class', 'date-picker');
    dList.append(newinput);
    var newdatepickr = $(".date-picker").datepicker();
});​
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/2pFAd/**

Answer (score -1):

If this is the jQuery UI datepicker you can simply call `.datepicker('refresh')` after each update.